# Can this probability $P(x+1>y, x+1>z, x+1>w, y>0, z>0, w>0)$ be solved analytically?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I am trying to find an analytical solution for this probability $$P(x+1>y,x+1>z,x+1>w,y>0,z>0,w>0)$$ where $x$, $y$, $z$ and $w$ have Gaussian distribution each have $\mu = 0$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Is there an analytical solution for this problem or I should solve it numerically?

Comment: @Yikai   yes x, y, z and w are independent and identically distributed

Comment: If they are iid Gaussian random variables, use that a [sum of Gaussian random variables is also Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables).

Comment: @Therkel, but I think this rule isn't valid due to the constraints on y, z, w:y>0, z>0, w>0 so they actually will have half-normal distribution

Comment: Can we assume that the means of the Gaussian distributions are all $0$?  Or that they all have the same variance?  Or anything whatsoever about the distributions?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, yes we can assume that they have zero mean and the same variance.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather use capital letters to denote random variables. So, we have

$$P(Y<X+1,Z<X+1,W<X+1,Y>0,Z>0,W>0)=$$
$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y<x+1,Z<x+1,W<x+1,Y>0,Z>0,W>0\mid X=x)f(x)\ dx=$$$$=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(Y<x+1,Z<x+1,W<x+1,Y>0,Z>0,W>0)f(x)\ dx$$

where  $f(x)$ is the common pdf of $X,Y,Z,W $ and $\{X=x\}$ was omitted because of the independence.

Now, if $x\ge -1$

$$P(Y<x+1,Z<x+1,W<x+1,Y>0,Z>0,W>0)=$$$$=P(0\le Y<x+1)P(0\le Y<x+1)P(0\le W<x+1)=$$
$$=\left[\Phi\left(\frac{x+1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^3$$
$0$ otherwise.

Thus,

$$P(Y<X+1,Z<X+1,W<X+1,Y>0,Z>0,W>0)=$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-1}^{\infty}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{x+1-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(-\frac{\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^3e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx.$$

From this point on you go numerically.

Comment: The OP now states that the mean is $\mu = 0$.  Will this simplify your integral and make it analytically soluble?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: Not really; a little. Just substitute $\mu=0$. ($\Phi(0)=\frac12$)

Comment: Yes... I realized that.  I'm trying to get the form:  $\int_{-1}^\infty {\rm Erf}[x] e^{-x^2/2} dx$ which gives $2 \sqrt{2 \pi } T\left(1,\sqrt{2}\right)$, Owen's T function.

Comment: But there is the cubic power... I confess, I cannot go any further.

Comment: Oh gosh yes... the cube.  I give up.

Comment: : ))) I gave up 7 hours ago.

Comment: @zoli I have one problem with this solution as when I'm trying another simple case $P(Y<X+1,Y>0)$ ,I try to find the distribution of a new random variable Z=X-Y and using the convolution theory to find the distribution of $Z$ (given the distribution of $Y$ is from 0 to inf) [link for convolution method] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_of_probability_distributions   however, I got different result  $P(Y<X+1,Y>0) = [erf(\frac{1}{2\sigma })+1]^{2}/8$  with \mu=0

Comment: Did you evaluate 

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-1}^{\infty}\left[\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\int_{-\infty}^{x+1}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ du-\frac12\right]e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dx?$$

Comment: the method of convolution give me another integration: $f_{z}=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma^2}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{-(z+y)^2}{2\sigma }}e^{-\frac{(y)^2}{2\sigma }} dy $ and $y>0$ adjust the limit of integration. then I found $P(Z>-1)$ where $Z=X-Y$

Comment: @M.F. But it is not enough to calculate  $P(Z>-1) $. We need $P(Z>-1\cap Y>0)$ where $Z$ and $Y$ aren't independent.

Comment: but I take $Y>0$ into account when calculating the distribution of $Z$. I am not sure if this is wrong because the results was matched with my simple Matlab code :                                                                                             >>sigmma=1;
>>x=sigmma*randn(1,1000000);
>>y=sigmma*randn(1,1000000);
>>count=0;
>>for jj=1:1000000
    
    if ((x(jj)+1)>y(jj))&&(y(jj)>0)
                   count=count+1;
                 
    end
end
>>probability=count/1000000;$

Comment: @Yes. I understand. Your calc is OK. However, you cannot disassemble $P(0<Y<X+1,0<Z<X+1,0<W<X+1)$ to get $P(0<Y<X+1)P(0<Z<X+1)P(0<W<X+1)$.